# How to run Python command in Docker and capture output and set it to environment variable

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a simple command for which I do not want to create a new python file and use it in docker run command rather I just want to run the command and get the output of the python command to set the environment variable.

```
ENV SECRET_KEY = "python code generating the secret key for the app"
```

Comment: Do you need that environment variable to be available everywhere or just for another command (that needs `SECRET_KEY` to be set)?

Comment: I want to set a system-level environment variable, not just python/script level.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `VAR="x" cmd` form:

```
FROM python:3.9-rc

RUN SECRET_KEY=$(python -c 'print("Here is a secret")') python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["SECRET_KEY"])'
```

Which should work as expected (2nd python command will have access to `SECRET_KEY`):

```sh
$ docker build -t secret_test . && docker run secret_test

Sending build context to Docker daemon  891.4kB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:3.9-rc
 ---> 0e09b0645b9e
Step 2/2 : RUN SECRET_KEY=$(python -c 'print("Here is a secret!")') python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["SECRET_KEY"])'
 ---> Running in 836e869b7e10
Here is a secret
Removing intermediate container 836e869b7e10
 ---> e95b48fc1fde
Successfully built e95b48fc1fde
Successfully tagged secret_test:latest
```

Comment: This won;t work. I need python to generate the key and it should be saved in SECRET_KEY so then I can use as ENV NEW_KEY=SECRET_KEY

Comment: I think it's not possible, however you could add an export to .bashrc so the environment variable is loaded when you run an interactive shell. You should probably update your question to ask for your whole need (including how you plan on using the exported variable).